# UIWebView href to open Map application failing

Tags: ios, dictionary

I have a UIWebView with a link as follows:

```
<a href="maps:saddr=Current Location&amp;daddr=Some place on Earth@38.043316,-120.397757">Get Directions</a>
```

Within Safari Mobile this link works just fine and opens the Map app with current location to lat/lon directions, but inside of my iPhone app in a UIWebView it results in this error:

```
didFailLoadWithError:Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 "The URL can't be shown"
```

I have added the following code to my shouldStartLoadWithRequest which checks for non-standard schemes and tries to launch it using the internal app:

```
if (![url.scheme isEqual:@"http"] && ![url.scheme isEqual:@"https"] ) {
     if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url]){
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
          return NO;
     }
}
return YES;
```

What could I be doing wrong?  This used to work in prior iOS versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct URL no longer starts with "maps". Instead use "http". You also need to specify the google servers.

Here is a link to the relevant docs: [Map Links](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1)

In your case it would look something like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current Location?daddr=Some place on Earth@38.043316,-120.397757
```

Please note that this code is not tested as I am not near my development machine right now.

Comment: The problem is this launches off Google in Safari Mobile and not the Maps app like it does within Safari Mobile.  I want to launch the Maps app.

Comment: Did you change your link in the UIWebView? Are you getting this error on the Simulator or on the device?

Comment: If I change to the link above it launches Safari and maps through the Google website and not the Maps application.  If I open this same web page in Safari Mobile it opens the Maps application.  Really confusing as this used to work the way I intended.

Comment: I don't disagree this is what they are showing for how their URL Type for Maps is handled, but it opens in Maps in Safari Mobile, but launches Safari Mobile and hits the Google website from UIWebView.

Comment: This was the correct action to take.  It turns out that the lack of the Maps app on the simulator and not reading the last part of the docks made quite a mess out of my Sunday.  Thanks for your help.